# How to get structure name?

Tags: prolog, functor

If I have `struct_name(a, b, c, d, e).`, how can I get the name of the struct? In this case, it would be `struct_name`.

Is there any specific command to do this or should I transform it in some way in a list (I tried and `atom_chars` doesn't work) and find save the characters until meeting `(` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`(=..)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D..)/2) predicate (this is an ISO-predicate, so it should work on (almost) all Prolog interpreters) that has on the left side a functor, and on the right side the name of the functor followed by its operands.

So:

```
?- struct_name(a, b, c, d, e) =.. L.
L = [struct_name, a, b, c, d, e].
```

You can thus obtain the name of the struct with:

```
get_name(A,N) :-
    A =.. [N|_].
```

When you then call it with `struct_name(a, b, c, d, e)`, it will give you:

```
?- get_name(struct_name(a, b, c, d, e),N).
N = struct_name.
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use `functor/3`.

Example:

```
?- Term = struct_name(a, b, c, d, e),
   functor(Term, F, Arity).
Term = struct_name(a, b, c, d, e),
F = struct_name,
Arity = 5.
```

Related term inspection predicates are `arg/3` and `(=..)/2`.

The use of such predicates often indicates a problem with your data structure design, and typically severly **limits the generality** of your relations.

Note in particular that you can use them *only if* their arguments are sufficiently instantiated.

For example:

```
?- functor(Term, F, A).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

This means that you can no longer use such predicates for **generating** answers.